# Iterate through each url in a large csv file with python, read it and get its json, then save them all to new csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner with Python and I'm trying to automate some tasks. What I cannot do is iterate through each url inside a large csv file after I read them with pandas and chunksize:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request, json 
import csv

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 9999999)

finalUrlList = []

    # Basically I want to append each URL from the csv to apiBase, then read the url and retrieve the JSON for each url and save it to a new csv file

apiBase = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykfWnqp7urCXZLmOOGnuWz6OcAufTFWNoOMHIew2nh3CWKriZS/exec?page="

csv_url='/Users/Andrea/Desktop/test.csv'
# use chunk size 
c_size = 50000


df_chunk = pd.read_csv(csv_url, chunksize=c_size, iterator=True)

# iterate through each url in the chunks and append it to the apiBase, then add it to a list

for chunk in df_chunk:
    urlToParse = apiBase + chunk
    finalUrlList.append(urlToParse) 

# iterate through each element of the list and process the url to retrieve json data

index = 0 

while index < len(finalUrlList):
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(finalUrlList[index]) as urlToProcess:
            data = json.loads(urlToProcess.read().decode())
            index = index + 1
    except Exception:
        print("An error occurred. I will try again!")
        pass


# Write data into a new csv file    

csvfile = "IndexedUrls.csv"
try:
    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        for val in data:
            writer.writerow([val])  
    print("Csv file saved successfully!")
except:
    print("An error occured, couldn't save csv file!")
```

The first part of reading the big file in chunks is successful, python can read the csv very fast. But then I cannot iterate through each url of the csv and perform the json reading task on each of them (maybe with multiprocessing to go faster in this last step cause it takes time as well to open the url, get the result, store it etc.).

Is there a fast way to achieve all this? thanks a lot for your help and sorry if code is crap but I'm a beginner and willing to learn a lot.

THANKS!

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the dataframe, will be easier to visualize. Use df.head() and share it.

Comment: I get an error which says: AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'head', I suppose because of the chunksize

Comment: `.head()` is a method applied only upon pandas dataframes. It has no relation with the size of the dataframe, it returns the first 5 rows. Probably, you are doing some mistake in calling the method on the appropriate dataframe object.

Comment: Sorry I did it wrong, there you go: https://1ce.org/1#S1dJApaGE .. I want to append those urls (massive csv file) to the apiBase url string in the code, then for each one read the URL output (JSON) and save it on a new csv. I can do it but it's extremely slow and takes ages, my goal is to speed this up and I was trying with chunksize and multiprocessing maybe. Thanks a lot :)